# Splitting values in one column to 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, pivot

I need to do the following in sql.

table 1:

```
Year  Client Investment

1999   X     100

1999   Y     200

2000   X     1000

2000   Y     2000
```

I want to display it in below format for my report:

```
Client 1999Year   2000Year 

X      100         1000
```

Any idea how to do the above?
I am using sql server 2008

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible solutions for this. One is by using `MAX()` and `CASE`,

```
SELECT  Client,
        MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR = 1999 THEN Investment END) [1999Year],
        MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR = 2000 THEN Investment END) [2000Year]
FROM    TableName
WHERE   Client = 'X'
GROUP   BY Client
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62c2f/1)

or using `PIVOT` function

```
SELECT Client,
       [1999] AS [1999YEAR],
       [2000] AS [2000YEAR] 
FROM
(
    SELECT  YEAR, CLient, Investment
    FROM    TableName
    WHERE   Client = 'X'
) pvt
PIVOT
(
    MAX(InvestMent)
    FOR YEAR IN ([1999],[2000])
) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62c2f/10)

Answer (score 6):

This type of data transformation is known an a `PIVOT`.  Some database products have a function that will turn the data from rows to columns.

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression in any database:

```
select client,
  sum(case when year = 1999 then investment end) Year_1999,
  sum(case when year = 2000 then investment end) Year_2000
from yourtable
group by client
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed9ee/1)

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use the `PIVOT` function to transform the data into columns:

```
select *
from
(
  select client, 
    'Year_'+cast(year as varchar(4)) year, 
    investment
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  sum(investment)
  for year in (Year_1999, Year_2000)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed9ee/3).

The other queries will work great if you have a known number of `year` values, but if you have an unknown number, then you will want to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Year_'+cast(year as varchar(4))) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT client,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select client, 
                  ''Year_''+cast(year as varchar(4)) year, 
                  investment
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(investment)
                for year in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed9ee/5).

This can also be done by joining on the table multiple times:

```
select t1.client,
  t1.investment Year_1999,
  t2.investment Year_2000
from yourtable t1
left join yourtable t2
  on t1.client = t2.client
  and t2.year = 2000
where t1.year = 1999
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed9ee/7)

All queries give the result:

```
| CLIENT | YEAR_1999 | YEAR_2000 |
----------------------------------
|      X |       100 |      1000 |
|      Y |       200 |      2000 |
```